# Program for addition and substraction with strings

Tags: java, string, char, int, charat

I've written a program where I want to make the addition and substraction of Strings where all Strings have the length of four and look like "+002", "+569", "-022", "-789" etc. I've tried to do it without using any multiplication, division or remainder, but only with addition and substraction as operations, but my problem is that certain cases don't work yet and I don't see why exactly or how I can fix it because it's difficult with such a long code to see well where the problem is exactly and what I should change. So here is the concerning method:

```
public static String add(String s1, String s2) {
        int number;
        int[] s = new int[4];
        String result = "";
        if (s1.contains("+") && s2.contains("+")) {
            result = "+";
            for (int i = 1; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
                if (!(s1.charAt(i) == 0 || s2.charAt(i) == 0)) {
                    if ((int) (s1.charAt(i)) + (int) (s2.charAt(i)) - 96 < 10) s[i] = (int) (s1.charAt(i)) + (int) (s2.charAt(i)) - 96;
                    else {
                        s[i] = (s1.charAt(i)) + (int) (s2.charAt(i)) - 106;
                    ++s[i - 1];
                    }
                }
                else if (s1.charAt(i) != 0 && s2.charAt(i) != 0) {
                    s[i] = (int) (s1.charAt(i)) + (int) (s2.charAt(i)) - 96;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (s1.contains("-") && s1.contains("-")) {
            result = "-";
            for (int i = 1; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
                if ((!(s1.charAt(i) == 0 || s2.charAt(i) == 0))) {
                    if ((int) (s1.charAt(i)) + (int) (s2.charAt(i)) - 96 < 10) s[i] = (int) (s1.charAt(i)) + (int) (s2.charAt(i)) - 96;
                    else {
                        s[i] = (s1.charAt(i)) + (int) (s2.charAt(i)) - 106;
                    ++s[i - 1];
                    }
                }
                else if (s1.charAt(i) != 0 && s2.charAt(i) != 0) {
                    s[i] = (int) (s1.charAt(i)) + (int) (s2.charAt(i)) - 96;
                }
            }
        }
        //if (s1.contains("+") && s1.contains("-") || s1.contains("-") && s1.contains("+"))
        else if (s1.contains("+") && s2.contains("-")) {
            char[] size1 = new char[s1.length()];
            char[] size2 = new char[s1.length()];
            for (int i = 1; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
                size1[i] = s1.charAt(i); 
                size2[i] = s2.charAt(i); 
            }
            if (size1[1] > size2[1]) result = "+";
            else if (size1[1] == size2[1]) {
                if (size1[2] > size2[2]) result = "+";
                else if (size1[2] == size2[2]) {
                    if (size1[3] > size2[3]) result = "+";
                    else if (size1[3] == size2[3]) return "+000";
                    else result = "-";
                }
                else result = "-";
            }
            else result = "-";
            for (int i = 1; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
                if (!(s1.charAt(i) == 0 || s2.charAt(i) == 0)) {
                    if (s1.charAt(1) < s2.charAt(1)) {
                        if (s1.charAt(2) <= s2.charAt(2)) {
                            if (s1.charAt(3) > s2.charAt(3)) {
                                s[2] = 10 - (s2.charAt(2) - s1.charAt(2));
                                s[3] = 10 - (s1.charAt(3) - s2.charAt(3));
                                --s[2];
                                s[1] = (s2.charAt(1) - s1.charAt(1));
                            }
                            else {
                                s[2] = (s2.charAt(2) - s1.charAt(2));
                                s[3] = (s2.charAt(3) - s1.charAt(3));
                                s[1] = s2.charAt(1) - s1.charAt(1);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            s[2] = 10 - (s1.charAt(2) - s2.charAt(2));
                            if (s1.charAt(3) < s2.charAt(3)) s[3] = (s2.charAt(3) - s1.charAt(3));
                            else {
                                s[3] = 10 - (s1.charAt(3) - s2.charAt(3));
                                --s[2];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i) < 0 && i == 1) s[i] = s2.charAt(i) - s1.charAt(i);
                    else if (s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i) < 0 && i > 1) {
                        s[i] = s2.charAt(i) - s1.charAt(i);
                    }
                    else s[i] = s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            char[] size1 = new char[s1.length()];
            char[] size2 = new char[s1.length()];
            for (int i = 1; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
                size1[i] = s1.charAt(i); 
                size2[i] = s2.charAt(i); 
            }
            if (size1[1] < size2[1]) result = "+";
            else if (size1[1] == size2[1]) {
                if (size1[2] < size2[2]) result = "+";
                else if (size1[2] == size2[2]) {
                    if (size1[3] < size2[3]) result = "+";
                    else if (size1[3] == size2[3]) return "+000";
                    else result = "-";
                }
                else result = "-";
            }
            else result = "-";
            for (int i = 1; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
                if (!(s1.charAt(i) == 0 || s2.charAt(i) == 0)) {
                    if (s1.charAt(1) > s2.charAt(1)) {
                        if (s1.charAt(2) >= s2.charAt(2)) {
                            if (s1.charAt(3) < s2.charAt(3)) {
                                s[2] = 10 - (s1.charAt(2) - s2.charAt(2));
                                s[3] = 10 - (s2.charAt(3) - s1.charAt(3));
                                --s[2];
                            }
                            else {
                                s[2] = (s1.charAt(2) - s2.charAt(2));
                                s[3] = (s1.charAt(3) - s2.charAt(3));
                                s[1] = s1.charAt(1) - s2.charAt(1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i) > 0 && i == 1) s[i] = s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i);
                    else if (s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i) > 0 && i > 1) {
                        s[i] = s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i);
                    }
                    else s[i] = s2.charAt(i) - s1.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < s.length; ++i) result += s[i];
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You can convert the strings into numbers in two lines of code and then calculate with them. Or is there a reason, why you calculate with strings?

Comment: I am not allowed to use type-converting methods from String to int.

Comment: Are you allowed to convert it on your own just with loops and charAt? Like so: digit0 + digit1 * 10 + ... (you don't even need a loop)

Comment: If I use a multiplication method defined by addition, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are allowed to use charAt(), you can convert the strings on your own:

```
// String s1 = "+123";
int d1 = (s1.charAt(1) - '0') * 100;
int d2 = (s1.charAt(2) - '0') * 10;
int d3 = (s1.charAt(3) - '0');
int num = d1 + d2 + d3;
```

Then you can just calculate with this number.

Comment: With a multiplication method defined by adsition yes. I also tried that way, but somehow there is an zero too much at my output.

Comment: It's always good to split your problem into subproblems, solve the subproblems individually and then combine the solutions to get the solution for the original problem. So I suggest, you implement the following functions individually: Multiplication, Division, StringToInt, IntToString. Then combine these functions to solve your problem. That way, your code is much easier to understand and it's easier to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
private static String add(String s1, String s2) {
    return intToString(stringToInt(s1) + stringToInt(s2));
}

private static int stringToInt(String string) {
    int multiplicand;
    int i = 0;

    multiplicand = string.charAt(0) == '+' ? 1 : -1;

    i += (string.charAt(1) - '0') * 100;
    i += (string.charAt(2) - '0') * 10;
    i += (string.charAt(3) - '0');

    return i * multiplicand;
}

private static String intToString(int i) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(i >= 0 ? "+" : "-");

    i = Math.abs(i);

    sb.append(i / 100);
    sb.append(i / 10 - (i / 100 * 10));
    sb.append(i - (i / 10 * 10));

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention certain cases don't work and you're not sure why. I think it has to do with your if-statements.

For example the first if in the first loop:

```
 if (!(s1.charAt(i) == 0 || s2.charAt(i) == 0)) {...}
```

will evaluate true in the exact same cases as the else if that follows it:

```
else if (s1.charAt(i) != 0 && s2.charAt(i) != 0) {...}
```

(Because in the first case you first evaluate if either value equals zero and then invert the result).

And then the first nested if in the first loop:

```
if ((int) (s1.charAt(i)) + (int) (s2.charAt(i)) - 96 < 10) {...}
```

Seems to me this will always evaluate true, because you are just the taking one char from both strings. So the highest outcome possible from addition is 18. Subtract 96 from that and it's bound to be less than 10.

In order to debug this and find the issue, I would recommend you to start by double-checking all the if-statements. Write down in comments or even make a diagram to establish when a certain step should be reached and what should happen there. Also, in case you are not yet using an IDE that might help as it will alert you to some of the issues in the logic.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to format your answer.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this mistake already, but that doesn't solve my problem.